# The supplied phased action failed with an exception - Flutter

Tags: java, flutter, gradle

i have this error in build.gadle file in flutter project

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir() is applicable for argument types: (File) values: [D:\flutterProjects\project\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug]
Could not find method destinationDir() for arguments [D:\flutterProjects\project\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug] on task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.

the red line i shown under the 'buildscript'

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

i tried to delete android folder